# jhipster gateway: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: jhipster-gateway

Used jhipster to create gateway. I use UAA for authorization. I didn't change any settings. Getting an error :( Maybe I need to add something else that wasn't done in the generation process?

URL: wss://**.com/websocket/tracker/883/jj2yk045/websocket

Cookie with access_token, session_token and XSRF-TOKEN.

Message: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Comment: I tried adding access_token as a parameter. - failed.

I tried adding _csrf as a parameter. - failed.

Answer (score 0):

The app was started with TLS disabled. This uses Nginx. After TLS enabled work fine.